Animated show with secret agent/spy kids?
I can't remember the name of this show that aired on Cartoon Network for the life of me. Its premise consisted of a group of preteen secret agents and the first episode, or at least the first episode I watched, involved the know-it-all of the group (I think he had red hair) learning to be less pretentious. I even recall a gag about him being able to tell time from the sun's position while he and the others were doing outdoor chores (He was raking).
From what I understand, the show was cancelled very early after its release. It had a very distinctive comic book motif along with that kind of art direction.
Just so I can get ahead of a few guesses, I'm already aware of Codename: KND and The Secret Saturdays. Please do not make these guesses.

It's implied from being on Cartoon Network, but for the sake of the more pedantic among the community, you might want to explicitly state that the cartoon was American and in English. Also, any idea when it originally aired? If not, when did you see it?

I wanna say it premiered somewhere between 2008-2011. I'm fairly certain the show was American because of the comic-influenced presentation, but I could be wrong.

It could have been the The Amazing Spiez!, which was a kind of spin-off series from the show Totally Spies that aired on Cartoon Network.
This show revolves around the lives of four sibling who also happen to be spies. Scene transitions involve moving from one comic panel to another or flipping through the pages of comic books, and captions in a block style common in American comic books.

Two of them are red-headed, with one being a bit of a know it all. I couldn't find the exact episode you were looking for, probably because the episode descriptions tend to be a bit vague, but this show seems like it fits with what you remember. I hope this helps.
IMDb Storyline:

Lee, Mark, Megan and Tony are secret agents for WOOHP (The World Organization of Human Protection) headed by Jerry Lewis and must juggle there daily lives. 

The show began airing in 2009 and lasted until 2012 with 52 episodes.

I think it's The Backyardigans, a Canadian–American CGI-animated musical TV series.
